# negative lookahead regex nginx 1.17.8

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I'm using **nginx/1.17.8** and I'm trying to redirect addresses in the format:

FROM: **/xxx/yyy/zzz**

TO: **/xxx/index.php/yyy/zzz**.

however the rule I created initially adds index.php infinitely, like this:

**/xxx/index.phpindex.phpindex.php.../yyy/zzz** until it fails ...

My rule:

```
location ~ ^/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ {
   try_files  $uri   $uri/ /$1/index.php/$2?$query_string;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;  
   access_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log;
}
```

I thought about doing a negative lookback to only enter 1x, but never execute this location, what am I doing wrong?

```
location ~ ^/([a-z]+)/(?!(index.php))/(.*)$ {
  try_files  $uri   $uri/ /$1/index.php/$2?$query_string;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;  
  access_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log;
}
```

Comment: Where is the location block that matches `index.php` and is it placed **before** this `location` block? Because that itself will prevent the loop and remove the need for a negative lookahead assertion.

Comment: Yes! that was the problem ... locations in magento are interpreted in the order of reading.